# Specify New Rows in Excel Text-Import Wizard?

Tags: excel, matlab, text, rows

The MATLAB code with which I've been collecting reaction time data has produced text files which do not have new paragraphs defined to indicate when a new row should be started, only tabs to delimit new columns.

I figured I could fix this by adding a character before the start of what should be each new row, and tell excel to use this to define the rows, however it looks like the text import wizard only allows you to specify delimiters for columns?

Is there some kind of workaround that will allow me to get my data imported correctly?

Comment: Write vba code to split into rows beforehand or fix it after the fact.

Comment: re: *'I figured I could fix this by adding a character'* - so why not add `\n` ?